# C# check if file is readable

Tags: c#, file

I need to read from a number of files but sometimes they are not available or cannot be read from current user. This is the code I'm using to check if file is valid but I think I'm not using the `using` statement correctly.

```
private static bool fileAccessible(string filePath) {
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)) {
        if (fs.CanRead) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false; // compiler says "unreachable code"
}
```

Should I insert a `try/catch` block outside the `using` statement to catch errors raised by unavailable file or will `using` go on without raising an error if `filePath` is not available?

Bonus question: is this the correct way to check if file is available and accessible? If the answer is Yes can I change `FileMode.Open` to `FileMode.Append` to perform the same check on writable files?

Comment: return false; // compiler says "unreachable code" is not needed.

Comment: the duplicate question addresses only permission issue, but I need also to check if file exists

Comment: @Naigel you can call `File.Exists(filepath)` to check files exists before using statement

Comment: The file system isn't solely under the control of your program. As such, this function might return `true` but by the time you actually take action based on this, the file may no longer be available. As such, I'd say that this is mostly a waste of time - just go ahead and try to *use* the file in whatever way you're going to and react to failures when they happen.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever do you think this approach should be used every time I interact with file? For example I need to write to some files, should I always use a pattern like `try { using (StreamWriter file = ... { file.Write("xxx") } }` ?

Comment: Yes, to an extent. For any resources outside of the control of your application (the file system, the network, remote servers) you *have* to write code that can cope with failures occurring at any time. No amount of up-front testing can answer the question "will I be able to complete task X?" Whether you choose to do this with a local exception handler immediately wrapped around each access or take a more global view is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it always better to use try catch as IO exception can occur due to some connectivity issue or file not found exception can occur.

```
   private static bool fileAccessible(string filePath) {
            return  File.Exists(filePath);

    }
```

Comment: what appens if `filePath` is not a valid path?

Comment: Corrected the code. Please verify,